# how to change record on runtime in table using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to use `ng-model` in Table and change value on runtime,

i have multiple records shows on table , there is two `<td>` have date-picker , start date , end date . i want change  date's in multiple rows , when i  change my date specific row using  ng-model it's change the date all rows , how to change specific row data using ng-model,

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in showAddedAssets  ">           
 <td >  <md-datepicker  id="startmd"name="plainnedstartdate" ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)"  ng-model="createCampaign.assets_planned_start_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
 <td  >  <md-datepicker name="plainnedenddate"  ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)" ng-model="createCampaign.assets_planned_end_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS FILE**

```
changedate(assetitem)
 {
   assetitem.assets_planned_start_date = this.assets_planned_start_date ;
   assetitem.assets_planned_end_date  = this.assets_planned_end_date;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add different ng-model to each row item

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in showAddedAssets  ">
    <td>  <md-datepicker id="startmd" name="plainnedstartdate" ng-change="changedate(row)" ng-model="row.createCampaign.assets_planned_start_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
    <td>  <md-datepicker name="plainnedenddate" ng-change="changedate(row)" ng-model="row.createCampaign.assets_planned_end_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
</tr>
```

so in your controller you can update date for that row

```
$scope.changedate = function(row)
 {
   row.assets_planned_start_date = some_date;
   row.assets_planned_end_date  = some_date;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change html

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in showAddedAssets ">           
 <td >  <md-datepicker  id="startmd_{{$index}} "name="plainnedstartdate" ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)"  ng-model="row.assets_planned_start_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
 <td  >  <md-datepicker id="endmd_{{$index}}" name="plainnedenddate"  ng-change="createCampaign.changedate(row)" ng-model="row.assets_planned_end_date" required></md-datepicker></td>
                  </tr>
```

and js file 
because you want to change all of rows so you should use angular.forEach for this work.

```
    changedate(row)
     {
       angular.forEach(this.showAddedAssets , function(item){
                item.assets_planned_start_date = row.assets_planned_start_date;
                item.assets_planned_end_date = row.assets_planned_end_date
        })
     }
```